# Rational number calculator

Tags: calculator, rational-numbers

I want to make a rational number calculator, but I don't know how to neglect some characters. E.g., if the program has to calculate the expression "2/9+9/3" and the answer should be in unsimplified form, how to neglect '/' in the above expression while taking input?

Comment: I don't see the problem here... if you're working with fractional numbers, the division operator / becomes the fraction indicator, i.e. any division is actually conversion to a fraction.

Comment: Have a look at the fraction module included in Python 2.6

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to define a syntax/parser that knows about rational numbers. For your sample input you would like to end up with a parse tree holding something like this:

```
   add(rational(2, 9)
       rational(9, 3))
```

Then you'd write code that knows about the various tricks used when calculating with rationals, so that the code implementing the `add` operation can, for instance, check for the [greatest common divisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of its input arguments, and transform the numbers to be addable.

In this case, it would probably rewrite the arguments to be `rational(2, 9)` and `rational(27, 9)`, then do the addition, thus ending up with `rational(29, 9)`.

You could have a separate function that does simplification, that can simplify that back down to `3+rational(2, 9)`.